# How to calculate water level in a tank or structure?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics, flow

How do you find the height of water in a rectangular tank if the flow into the tank is the same as the rate out the tank? Let's say the water gets at a rate of 10 gallons per minute through a 18 inch pipe and gets out at the same rate through a 18 inch pipe. How do I calculate the height of water in the tank? I'm calculating the hydraulic profile; I know that I need the elevation, the height of water, and head loss.

Answer (score 0):

if the rate in = rate out then surely the  height must be zero. or at a constant height of your choosing given an initial surplus of water in the tank. although In the real world it will never he the same